# Node.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some Node.js code that gives this error

Could anybody tell me what does this error mean and how do I do to solve it?

Thank you very much!

```
if (fn.handle && fn.set) app = fn;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

at Function.app.use (/Users/sylvia/Documents/FE/Daily-

Learning/Node/final/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:110:9)

at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sylvia/Documents/FE/Daily- Learning/Node/final/server.js:46:8)

at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

at Module.load (module.js:343:32)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

at startup (node.js:140:18)

at node.js:1043:3
```

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var expressStatic = require('express-static');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');
var expressRoute = require('express-route');
var multer = require('multer');
var multerObj = multer({dest:'./static/upload'});

var server = express();
server.listen(8080);

server.use(multerObj.any());
server.use(cookieParser());

(function(){
    var keys=[];

    for(var i=0;i<100000;i++){
        keys[i]='a_' + Math.random();
    }

    server.use(cookieSession({
        name: 'sess_id',
        keys: keys,
        maxAge: 20*60*1000 //20mins
    }));
})();

server.engine('html',consolidate.ejs);

server.set('views','template');
server.set('view engine','html');

var r1 = express.Router();
var r2 = express.Router();

server.use('/article/',r1);

r1.get('/1.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('aaa').end();
});

r1.get('/2.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('bbb').end();
});

server.use('/blog/',r2);

r2.get('/a.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('ccc').end();
});

r2.get('/b.html',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('ddd').end();
});


server.use(expressStatic('./static/'));
```

Comment: please format the code appropriately

Comment: Is it the complete code?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia Yes

Comment: This line `server.listen(8080);`should be the last one, no? Btw cant you debug and see where the error happens?

Comment: There is no `if` in the posted code.

Comment: Could you tell me how to debug?

Comment: What is in line 110? That the message says to look at.

Comment: @AjAX there is no line 110 in my code~~

Comment: It is in `/Users/sylvia/Documents/FE/Daily-

Learning/Node/final/node_modules/express/lib/application.js`.

Comment: @AjAX  110 is if (fn.handle && fn.set) app = fn;

Comment: Can you share your packages.json file please ? Thanks

Comment: `fn` is unknown. The variable or function is — not — defined. Look it up!

Comment: @Farhan Tahir here it is
{
  "name": "final",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "consolidate": "^0.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "ejs": "^2.5.8",
    "express": "^3.0.6",
    "express-route": "^0.1.4",
    "express-static": "^1.2.5",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0"
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in old version of express.js. The error is thrown on line

```
server.use('/article/',r1);
```

because `r1` is undefined. You need to upgrade your express version to 4.x.x since routers are not available in 3.x.x version. You can do that with this command:

```
npm install express@4.13.4 --save
```